# inner class in typescript nativescript

Tags: nativescript

I want to use a Java inner class in typescript in `nativescript` framework for Android.

First I tried to put it in a separate class:

```
  class LocalBinder extends android.os.Binder {
   private foregroundService;

   constructor(foregroundService) {
      super();
      this.foregroundService = foregroundService;
      return global.__native(this);
   }

   public getService() {
      return this.foregroundService;
   } 
}
```

and put this line in `ForegroundService`:

```
private mLocalBinder = new LocalBinder(this);
```

but I failed.

Here is the Java code I want to rewrite to typescript in `nativescript`:

```java
public class ForegroundService extends Service {

  private final LocalBinder mLocalBinder = new LocalBinder();

  public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
    public ForegroundService getService() {
      return ForegroundService.this;
    }
  }

  .......

}
```